# Ask a particular MATLAB worker to do something prior to parfor?

Tags: matlab

I just started playing around with the MATLAB parallel computation, more specifically, `parfor`. Basically, I need to connect each MATLAB worker to one external program (COMSOL, actually) by port number, before the parallel computation starts, as the calculation requires the external program.

Say, in total, I have 10 workers, 10 ports (9001 - 9010), and 10 external programs. Now prior to entering `parfor`, I have to connect each of the works to one of the programs via one of the ports. i.e.,

```
no_workers = 10;
matlabpool open no_workers;

for idx = 1:1:no_workers
    port_no = 9000+idx;
    connect(worker_ID, program_ID, port_no); % how???
end

% computation starts
parfor idx = 1:1:no_workers
    compute();
end

matlabpool close;
```

How may I do this?

Comment: Would it work to put this simply at the start of the parfor loop? (So inside the parfor?)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin The thing is the connection kinda takes time and it is error-prone. So I am trying to avoid repeatedly doing that. Moreover, the connection only should happen at the start up phase. Once it is connected, the following running should not break the connection and reconnect.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. In both of our codes the `connect` function is called 10 times, and before the corresponding worker does anything else.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Oh, sorry for the confusion. There will be another loop wrapping the computation parfor loop. Hence, if I put the connection command in the parfor loop, it is executed more by a multiplying factor.

Comment: In that case my first thought would be to try moving that loop inside the parfor loop. In general I believe parfor has some overhead, so I suppose you want to keep it on a higher level if possible.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Can I do `parfor connect() end; for parfor compute() end end`? My concern is once the workers are created and connected to program in the 1st parfor, will them remain connected in the 2nd parfor?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would expect the program to look like, but unfortunately I cannot try it myself:

```
no_workers = 10;
matlabpool open no_workers;

parfor idx = 1:1:no_workers
    port_no = 9000+idx;
    connect(worker_ID, program_ID, port_no); % how???
    compute();
end

matlabpool close;
```

Answer (score 0):

The PARFOR solution above will probably work, but you might as well be sure and use [`spmd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/spmd.html) and [`labindex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/labindex.html).

```
spmd
    port_no = 9000 + labindex;
    connect(...);
end
```

If the "connect" method returns a connection object, you can use the [Worker Object Wrapper](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31972-worker-object-wrapper) to hold on to it and pass it in to subsequent `parfor` loops. You'd do that like so:

```
spmd
    c = connect(...);
end

% build the wrapper
w = WorkerObjWrapper(c);

% use the wrapper inside PARFOR
parfor idx = 1:N
    useConnection(w.Value);
end

% disconnect at the end.
spmd
    disconnect(w.Value);
end
```